# Profiler in Android Studio is blank when opening heap dump

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a heap dump using the following vm options when running my program `-agentlib:hprof=heap=dump,format=b`. This creates a `java.hprof` file. When I go to the profiler in Android Studio and try to open the file it says "Fetching data..." and then it just goes blank with nothing there. Any reason why?

[image]

I'm not able to "attach" the profiler to my process as it isn't a supported device. It's actually just a JUnit test that I'm profiling. Therefore, I had to add the vm options above to create a heap dump.